# Jersey example in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, jersey

I'm new to IntelliJ.  I have the traditional "HelloWorld" Jersey app running:

```
package restHello;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Path("/resource")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String getStuff() {
        return "works";
    }
}
```

How do I add Jersey jars to IntelliJ so it can 1.) resolve the imports and 2.) allow me to use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON instead of "text/plain"?

Comment: where you successful adding jars to intellij, am using latest 11.1 version and i have added jars properly but those are not referenced by IntelliJ

Comment: See [Attaching a RESTful WebServices facet to an existing module](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/preparing-for-rest-development.html#d1459855e667)